# Webform event registration: Show event data by token

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

Is there a way to use tokens to display event's data in a drupal webform? Like

[event.title]
[event.date]
[event.description]

and stuff like that...

Comment: If you add an event in the Events section of webform it will show those fields... but not sure whether that is really what you're asking.  Is this a conceptual question (is it possible...) or because you have tried and can't get the result you want?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean »display as form inputs«. I want to use those fields in the welcome text like »Registration for event [event.title] on [event.date] in [event.location]«. And yes I have tried but it was kind of poking around...